# c# - .NET 5 Bootstrap MVC with value from a database (oracle)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-5

For context purpose, I'm a complete beginner trying to learn something in my spare time. I want to implement a checkbox list using bootstrap, and the values in the checkbox list should come from a query from a database.

From [Bootstraps page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/checks-radios/), I cannot understand how to display a list of value from a query in a checkbox: every examples on the page are with records written directly on the view.

Let's say I have a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FRUITS FROM DB_FRUIT
```

That gives 3 results:

```
BANANA
APPLE
MANGO
```

I want a checkbox list on my page that displays them, and if I add or eliminate a record in the DB, I want them to be automatically updated on the page.

What I did for didn't work, I've followed various tutorial on the internet trying to modify my code accordingly. I'm not interested in receiving a solution per se, I want to understand how it is done: could you please lend me a hand/link me a guide?

Class (with db connection):

```
public List<string> GetFruits()
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();

    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT distinct FRUITS FROM DB_FRUIT";
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<string> Fruits= new List<string>();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Fruits.Add(dr["FRUITS"].ToString());
        }

        return Fruits;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FruitLoader()
List<string> Fruits = _Fruits.GetFruits();
ViewData["Fruits"] = Fruits;
```

What I do on the view with the ViewData Fruits:

```
<partial name="~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml" />

    @{ 
        List<string> Fruits= (List<string>)ViewData["Fruits"];
    }
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    Select Test: <br />
    @{
        var select = ViewData["Fruits"] as SelectList;
        if (select !=null && select.ToList().Count>0)
        {
            foreach (var item in select.ToList())
            { 
               <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems"  value="@item.Value" @(Html.Raw(item.Selected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) /> @item.Text  <br/>
            }
        }
     } 
</div>
```

However, it's not working, so I guess I'm utterly wrong.

Comment: What are you doing with `ViewData["Fruits"]` on the view page? Can you share the view code please?

Comment: You need to update the question add the code there...

Comment: You need to be more specific about what isn't working. Is it not updating the data once you change it or is it not displaying your data properly (have you checked the html in the page). Have you debugged with breakpoints in your controller to see if your query returns data? So on so forth

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> I want a checkbox list on my page that displays them, and if I add or
> eliminate a record in the DB, I want them to be automatically updated
> on the page.However, it's not working, so I guess I'm utterly wrong.

Actually, based on your shared code snippet and description upto pulling fruits list from database and binding them in ViewData["Fruits"] is alright. In fact, Controller and GetFruits method also fine.

**What Causing the checkbox empty:**

Within view you are doing unnecessary casting into selectList at the same time,selectList used for dropdown list but you are using checkbox.  Therefore, following code is causing issue and its not required for your scenario:

```
var select = ViewData["Fruits"] as SelectList;
```

Which causing null data and consequently, your checkbox list is not populating accordingly as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

**How to resolve:**

You can directly loop over `List<string> Fruits` which is containing list of string which is fruits collection. Thus, you can get all fruits in items, no additional casting required. You can refer following code.

```
@{
    List<string> Fruits = (List<string>)ViewData["Fruits"]!;
}
<div class="form-group">
    Select Test: <br />

    @{
        if (Fruits!.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Fruits)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="@item" value="@item" /> <strong>@item</strong>  <hr>
            }
        }
    }
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** In addition, if you want to get value back to controller again in that case you should replace foreach loop with for loop. If you still want to know more details on checkbox list you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0#additional-resources)

Comment: Ok! You can close my question

Comment: If it resolve your issue you can accept it there is no option for closing.